# Коллизия платформы и мячика

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

Помогите создать коллизию мячика и платформы в функции roll

```
from tkinter import *

def roll():
  global ball_y
  global dy
  global ball_x
  global dx
  ball_x = ball_x + dx
  if ball_x > 700 or ball_x < 0:
    dx = -dx
  ball_y = ball_y + dy
  if ball_y > 500 or ball_y < 0:
    dy = -dy
  canv.coords(ball, ball_x, ball_y, ball_x+100, ball_y+100,)
  form.after(10,roll)
def pad_move(event):
    global pad_x 
    pad_x = event.x
    canv.coords(platform, pad_x-50,500, pad_x+50, 530)


form = Tk()
form.title("Arkanoid TEST")
form.geometry("800x600")



canv = Canvas(form, width = 800, height = 600, bg="lightblue")
canv.pack()


ball_x=0
ball_y=0
dx = 5
dy = 5


ball = canv.create_oval(ball_x, ball_y, ball_x+100, ball_y+100, fill = "Black")


form.after(0,roll)
pad_x = 150
platform = canv.create_rectangle(pad_x, 500,pad_x+100, 530, fill = "Black")

form.bind("<Motion>", pad_move)
form.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это уже третий (или второй) никнейм с попыткой написать арканоид, при этом выкладывающий одинаковый шаблон кода. По крайней мере эти глобальные переменные в Python на функции `roll` я точно помню..

Comment: @AlexKrass, [это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/913112/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin оно самое.

Answer (score 1):

У нас не поощряется прямая работа за автора, если он не продемонстрировал свои попытки решения задачи. Поэтому давайте сделаем так - я вам опишу простой алгоритм решения, а вы уж сами его попробуете реализовать в своей программе.

На данный момент у вас есть координаты сторон шара и прямоугольника, сравнивая соответствующие координаты, вы сможете определить, как они располагаются друг относительно друга.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шар и прямоугольник имеют пересечения при четырех условиях для положения по координате X и координате Y. Сравнивая нужные координаты, вы получите результат.

1. Правая сторона шара находится правее левой стороны прямоугольника.
2. Левая сторона шара находится левее правой стороны прямоульника.
3. Низ шара находится ниже верха прямоугольника.
4. Верх шара находится выше верхней стороны прямоугольника.

Столкновение происходит только тогда, когда все четыре условия являются верными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого только нужно изменить скорость по оси X или Y на противоложную. Для этого надо сравнить, какие стороны находятся ближе к друг другу и изменить скорость по нужной оси. Не меняйте скорость только по одной вертикальной оси, иначе может шар зайти сбоку и вы получите зигзагообразные скачки внутри платформы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае это самый простой способ определения столкновения для фигур. Он же вам пригодится для того, чтобы определять столкновения на блоках.

Comment: Извините не знал учту

Comment: @ToujaKonea, это обычно в туре и справке описано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Платформа создана для помощи как начинающим, так и профессиональным программистам. Но не в качестве бесплатных ответов для тех, кто не хочет учиться и понимать. Для людей тут подобное просто трата времени, в отличие от других форумов. Поэтому к вопросам "вот условие, дайте ответ" тут относятся не очень положительно. Если же вы предоставляете свои варианты решения (пускай и нерабочие), объясняете где возникло непонимание, просите совета, алгоритма и т.д., то ваш шанс на ответ резко возрастает.